# How to vectorize an operation on a "series" of vectors in R

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have a function in R which takes a scalar and a vector as arguments, to perform some operation on them returning a single value.

Given a "series" of scalars (here, the vector `mya`) and a "series" of vectors (here, the matrix `myv`), how can I vectorize the call to `myf` so that each element in `mya` goes with the corresponding vector in `myv`?

```
mya = 1:3
myv = matrix(1:30, 10, 3)

myf = function(a, v) {
  return(sum(a / (a/v + 1)))
}

sapply(1:3, function(x) {myf(mya[x], myv[,x])})
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

So above I would like to avoid the looping `sapply` operation to do directly something like:

```
myf(mya, myv)
# [1] 49.37443   <- Here I would like 3 values
```

The big issue here is performance: in my real situation, `mya` and `myv` would have more than 10e6 values or vectors respectively, and `myf` is much more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, your `myv` might be organized as a series of vectors, one column each; it is better for many tools to convert it into a `list` of vectors.

```r
asplit(myv, 2)
# [[1]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# [[2]]
#  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# [[3]]
#  [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

### base R

`sapply`/`lapply` are to a single vector/list as `mapply`/`Map` are to `n` of them.

```r
Map(myf, mya, asplit(myv , 2))
# [[1]]
# [1] 7.980123
# [[2]]
# [1] 17.64959
# [[3]]
# [1] 26.80944
mapply(myf, mya, asplit(myv , 2))
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

### tidyverse

The order of arguments is different, and instead of individual arguments it needs all of them in a `list` itself.

```r
purrr::pmap(list(mya, asplit(myv , 2)), myf)
# [[1]]
# [1] 7.980123
# [[2]]
# [1] 17.64959
# [[3]]
# [1] 26.80944
purrr::pmap_dbl(list(mya, asplit(myv , 2)), myf)
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

---

Alternative approach, given the comments.

This approach truly is vectorized, but has deconstructed the function a little.

```r
colSums(t(mya / (mya / t(myv) + 1)))
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

To get to this point, one needs to recognize where `t`ranspose and such is necessary. I'll start with some known points:

```r
mya[1] / myv[,1] + 1
#  [1] 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000 1.200000 1.166667 1.142857 1.125000 1.111111 1.100000
```

In order to mimic that with matrices (and not just vectors), we might try

```r
(mya / myv + 1)
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#  [1,] 2.000000 1.181818 1.142857
#  [2,] 2.000000 1.250000 1.045455
#  [3,] 2.000000 1.076923 1.086957
#  [4,] 1.250000 1.142857 1.125000
#  [5,] 1.400000 1.200000 1.040000
#  [6,] 1.500000 1.062500 1.076923
#  [7,] 1.142857 1.117647 1.111111
#  [8,] 1.250000 1.166667 1.035714
#  [9,] 1.333333 1.052632 1.068966
# [10,] 1.100000 1.100000 1.100000
```

But if you notice, the division of `mya` over `myv` is column-wise, so it is expanding to

```r
c(mya[1] / myv[1,1], mya[2] / myv[2,1], mya[3] / myv[3,1], mya[1] / myv[4,1], ...)
```

where we would prefer it to be transposed. Okay, so we transpose it so that the *rows* of `myv` are vertical for the division.

```r
(mya / t(myv) + 1)[1,]
#  [1] 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000 1.200000 1.166667 1.142857 1.125000 1.111111 1.100000
```

That's better. Now we need to do the same for the next step. That brings us to

```r
t(mya / (mya / t(myv) + 1))
#            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#  [1,] 0.5000000 1.692308 2.625000
#  [2,] 0.6666667 1.714286 2.640000
#  [3,] 0.7500000 1.733333 2.653846
#  [4,] 0.8000000 1.750000 2.666667
#  [5,] 0.8333333 1.764706 2.678571
#  [6,] 0.8571429 1.777778 2.689655
#  [7,] 0.8750000 1.789474 2.700000
#  [8,] 0.8888889 1.800000 2.709677
#  [9,] 0.9000000 1.809524 2.718750
# [10,] 0.9090909 1.818182 2.727273
```

Since you wanted to sum across each of the `mya` values. Knowing that we have three in `mya` and we see three columns, one might infer we need to sum each column. We can prove that empirically:

```r
sum(mya[1] / (mya[1] / myv[,1] + 1))
# [1] 7.980123
colSums(t(mya / (mya / t(myv) + 1)))
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

But really, we don't need to `t`ranpose then sum columns when we can not-transpose and sum the rows :-)

```r
rowSums(mya / (mya / t(myv) + 1))
# [1]  7.980123 17.649590 26.809440
```

Comment: Thanks! The `purrr::pmap_dbl` solution is nice and quite fast! But if I am not wrong, such mapping is not really a vectorization, so does this mean that the vectorization of a "series" (as a list for example, as you point out) of vectors is not possible?

Comment: This is a vectorization of multiple vectors/lists. What makes you say that this mapping is not so?

Comment: I guess I am being confused as I don't really know what is happening behing the mapping, I suspect some looping in there but my own suspicion is a bit abstract. And perhaps I am not the only one puzzled there -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Applying a user-defined function over every element of a vector/list will almost certainly require a `for` loop somewhere in the stack. So technically you are correct: none of the `*apply*` functions (in base R or `purrr`) do true vectorization, not like `1:10 * 2` is vectorized.

Comment: I think I launched into a different direction with the first iteration of the answer. Take a look at the second part, something that works with *this* user-defined function logic. It is not generally applicable across all UDFs, but works when it is mathematically straight-forward. I hope the walk-through helped. (This will be significantly faster than any `*apply` variant.)

Comment: Great! The second part of your question is really what I was looking for - thanks (especially as I had already accepted the answer - very nice)! Indeed faster and truly vectorized. In case useful to others: in my real case, I played in addition with `tcrossprod` and `sweep` to reach my goal. Leads to faster solution. [and in the real end, computing everything in C++ through `Rcpp` was the fastest - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006146/fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-pass-rows-of-a-large-data-frame-as-arguments-t]